# How to create Json Object and send to server using retrofit in Android

Tags: android, retrofit

This is my Registration Page.I want to post all Data to Sever using Retrofit library via Json Object or bean Class. I m using Retrofit 1.9.

```
private void insertUser(String name, String password,String contact_Number,String email, String country_Code,String deviceId){
    //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
    //Creating a RestAdapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL) //Setting the Root URL
            .build(); //Finally building the adapter

    //Creating object for our interface
    RequestInterface api = adapter.create(RequestInterface.class);

    //Defining the method insertuser of our interface
    api.insertUser(

            //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts
            et_Name.getText().toString(),
            et_ContactNumber.getText().toString(),
            et_CountryCode.getText().toString(),
            et_Email.getText().toString(),
            et_Password.getText().toString(),
            et_DeviceId.getText().toString(),


            //Creating an anonymous callback
            new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Response result, Response response) {

                    //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                    //Creating a bufferedreader object
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    //An string to store output from the server
                    String output = "";

                    try {
                        //Initializing buffered reader
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                        //Reading the output in the string
                        output = reader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Displaying the output as a toast
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        );
    }

}
```

This is my Interface class Request Interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/create_site_client.php")
    public void insertUser(
            @Field("name") String name,
            @Field("contact_no") String contact_Number,
            @Field("country_code") String country_Code,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("device_id") String device_id,

            Callback<Response> callback);
```

I want to make login and registration page using Retrofit
when i m runing above code its give error:

{"status":"fail","error":{"error_code":1062,"error_message":"Duplicate entry '7777777777' for key 'contact_no'"},"data":null}

and i want to send user input  to sever :  {"name":"dfgfg","contact_no":"7777777777","country_code":"91","email":"dd@gmail.com","password":"123","device_id":"1234"}

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the logcat for data you are sending. I observed from error message that phone no 7777777777 is already saved in your server data base and it is unique. So you are getting error. Please try with other real phone number.

Comment: {"status":"fail","error":{"errorcode":"9001","errormesssage":"Please enter all required filed"},"data":"null"}

Comment: Please paste data you are sending. If retrofit log is not enabled, enable it and check. You have not added any check in code, so make sure you are filling all necessary field. If there is any header required in api, please check.

Comment: This my Api  which i m sending  server. http://www.example.com/site/create_site_client.php. And above i mention in my interface that all field i m sending to server.

Answer (score 0):

1. By creating placeholder class object And passing string value in it.
2. If I m using  retrofit 1.9.0, u must have to pass user object  and Callback as shown below.

   ```
   User user = new User(name,email,contact_no,country_code,password,device_id);

   //Defining the method insertuser of our interface

   api.insertUser(user,new Callback<User>() {

       @Override
       public void success(User result, Response response) {
           BufferedReader reader = null;

           //An string to store output from the server
           String output = "";

           try {
               //Initializing buffered reader
               reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));

               //Reading the output in the string
               output = reader.readLine();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           //Displaying the output as a toast
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
   ```

My interface is like:

```
@POST("/create_site_client.php")
 void insertUser(@Body User user,Callback<User> cb);
```